# Router to Router connection

Tags: networking, router, routing, lan, wan

I got a problem with my network. For simplicity reason I will say Router A and Router B. Router B is connected through a wire with Router A. I ran from the Router A port straight into the WAN Port from Router B and this creates an entirely new network.

Is there a method to make one big network so I can access devices that are connected at Router A through Router B or should I make a routing table so Router A knows the other network?

edit: For example I want to stream something to a TV that's connected with Router A and my device is connected to Router B

Greetings from Germany!

Comment: Grüßen aus England! If you can't set router B into AP mode, as suggested by David Woodward below, you may do better to forget about it and buy a network extender instead. It may also be possible to set routes between the two networks, though I've never needed to do this myself.

Comment: It works now with ap mode. But thank you as well!

Comment: Btw: Schönen Tag!

Comment: Provide the router brand and model, and helpers may be able to find specific details to help you change settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking to do would normally be accomplished using a switch or wireless access point rather than a router.

However, many routers have an "access point" mode that may help achieve this.

You might also be able to accomplish this by:

1. Set a static LAN IP address on router B that is in the same subnet used for the LAN on router A *(make sure its outside of the DHCP address pool on router A to prevent clients from trying to use it)*
2. Disable the DHCP server/service on router B.
3. Plug the cable into one of the other router "switch ports" on router B rather than the "WAN" port.

What model router(s) are you using?

Comment: Thanks, just put Router B into ap mode so everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

As the above poster says, routers usually have a separate mode for this type of thing. You may find your router offers it as "modem mode" instead of "router mode" in the case of Virgin Media's SuperHub's and many ISP basic ones, sometimes it is also listed under the Connection Type where you will normally see DSL/ASDL/VDSL/Ethernet, with Ethernet being the option for what you want to achieve. It vastly depends on what model of router you are using to extend the network with.

Ensure that you don't have two DHCP servers running, that the DHCP server you do have running doesn't issue clients with the IP of "Router B" (the extending router) and you should be ready to go.